# Mouse move (cursor) scroll not working on chrome but mouse wheel is working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, mousedown

This problem is only with Chrome Based browsers. In Safari and Firefox they both working correctly (both mouse move scroll and Wheel scroll).

[It scrolls perfectly on Firefox when I click and drag on Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYkpB.gif)

```
<div
    ref={containerRef}
    style={{
      width: "700px",
      height: "700px",
      overflow: "auto",
      cursor: "default",
      scrollBehavior: "smooth",
    }}
    onScroll={handleScrollTo}
  >
    <div
      className="relative w-[10000px] h-[10000px] bg-[#1E1E1E] overflow-hidden"

    >

    </div>
  </div>
```